# SPA ASP.NET Core MVC with scaffolding templates for client side validation

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-core, breeze, single-page-application, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm trying to create my first single page application with asp.net core mvc and knockout js (probably, but anything plausible would do). My app is pretty data intensive and that is why I love Scaffolding templates of asp.net mvc as they're not only customizable but also take care of validation which is precisely why I asked this question. So, is there a way to scaffold my way out in an spa? As web api controllers can be easily generated for a given data source but it's the views and validation that I want to scaffold as well. Or, is there a way to alter pre-written t4 scaffolding templates for an isomorphic spa framework to use without api controllers i.e. same ol' scaffolded controllers with views.

***Edit:*** To put it more precisely, Is there a way to generate **CRUD Forms** with **Validation** based on **viewmodel** in an **SPA Framework**?

I've found a library called **breeze js**, says it can do validation based on Entity Framework model's **Data Annotations**. Let's see how it goes.

Comment: no answers yet? ;( such a barren place stackoverflow has become.

Comment: Your question is poorly formatted and quite broad.  It also gives the impression that you aren't interested in solving a problem as much as expecting others to present you with a solution.  A question that starts off with "if you find this question offensive" and ends with "P.S. I'm lazy." isn't going to get a lot of people excited to offer help.

Comment: @Claies but that is the truth :-P

Comment: You made a comment about there not being any answers, I was just trying to provide you with a bit of insight as to why that might be the case.  Take it however you like, but if you really are interested in getting answers to your question, take some time to format the question so it is more readable, and remove the personal rants.

Comment: @Claies Is it fine now? Thanks.

Comment: I've found a library called breeze js, says it can do validation based on Entity Framework model's Data Annotations.

Comment: this might help:  https://www.dotvvm.com/
https://www.dotnetrocks.com/?show=1345